# Избавиться от дублирования кода в методе

Tags: c#

День добрый помогите избавиться от дублирования кода в методе IndexOfInnerRectangle

```
using System;
 
namespace Rectangles
{
    public static class RectanglesTask
    {
        // Пересекаются ли два прямоугольника (пересечение только по границе также считается пересечением)
        public static bool AreIntersected(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
        {
            return Math.Min(r1.Right, r2.Right) >= Math.Max(r1.Left, r2.Left) &&
                   Math.Min(r1.Bottom, r2.Bottom) >= Math.Max(r1.Top, r2.Top);
        }
 
        public static int IntersectionSquare(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
        {
            return AreIntersected(r1, r2) ? (Math.Min(r1.Right, r2.Right) - Math.Max(r1.Left, r2.Left)) *
                                            (Math.Min(r1.Bottom, r2.Bottom) - Math.Max(r1.Top, r2.Top))
                                            : 0;
        }
 
 
        public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
        {
            if (r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom)
                return 0;
            else if (r1.Left <= r2.Left && r1.Right >= r2.Right && r1.Top <= r2.Top && r1.Bottom >= r2.Bottom)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Реализуйте в классе RectanglesTask.cs три метода для работы с прямоугольниками:

    определение, есть ли у двух прямоугольников хотя бы одна общая точка (и граница и внутренность считаются частью прямоугольника);
    вычисление площади пересечения;
    определение, вложен ли один в другой.

Comment: Так у Вас дублирования кода и нет. Есть два условия, которые хоть и довольно похожи, но не полностью дублируют друг друга. Чего Вы хотите добиться?) Если просто кода "покрасивше" - то чекните вариант, предложенный в другой ветке - на Шарпе тож должно взлететь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27768039/find-out-if-a-rectangle-is-inside-another-rectangle-c

Comment: В System.Drawing есть структура [Rectangle](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.rectangle?view=net-5.0). У неё есть такие методы, как `Contains`, `Intersect` и другие. Возможно, их использование упростит ваш код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно вынести код проверки в отдельный метод

```cs
public static int IndexOfInnerRectangle(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    if (IsInBounds(r1, r2))
        return 0;
    if (IsInBounds(r2, r1))
        return 1;
    return -1;
}

private bool IsInBounds(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2)
{
    return r1.Left >= r2.Left && r1.Right <= r2.Right && r1.Top >= r2.Top && r1.Bottom <= r2.Bottom;
}
```